# Find a letter's alphabetical score

Tags: ruby, character

What would be the right way to find the location of a character within the alphabet? For example:

```
"A".find_score # => 1
"C".find_score # => 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"A".ord
```

returns 65, the numeric code for "A", which is what the alphabet starts at. If you want it to start at 1 you could just subtract 64:

```
def get_code(c)
  c.upcase.ord - 'A'.ord + 1
end
```

which works like:

```
get_code('A') # 1
get_code('B') # 2
get_code('C') # 3
```

Comment: `c.upcase.ord - 'A'.ord + 1` makes it self-documenting, but does involve an extra calculation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is actually better semantically. It does not explicitly introduce a magic number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I updated my post, I like your suggestion, thanks!