# Ruby inbuilt method to get the position of letter in the alphabet series?

Tags: ruby

Input: `str = "stackoverflow"`

Output: `[19 20 1 3 11 15 22 5 18 6 12 15 23]`

Do we have any method to get the position of the letters in ruby?

So that I can use something like `str.chars.map { |al| al.some_method }`.

`str.chars = ["s", "t", "a", "c", "k", "o", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "o", "w"]`

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes. I tried it with indexOf methods and joins but this returns me the position inside the array. In fact, that is what indexOf do. I googled list of methods to get the position of the alphabet but could not find any.

Comment: I have a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a letter's alphabetical score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747126/find-a-letters-alphabetical-score)

Comment: @Xero I was looking for an inbuilt method in ruby.

Comment: @vikas95prasad you can use monkey patching to do this. when you could called it in a inbluid way https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/

Comment: @vikas95prasad _"I tried it with indexOf"_ – that's not Ruby anymore ;-)

Comment: @vikas95prasad If there were an inbuilt method, it would have been the first answer. So in short, there isn't one. Ruby does a lot of helpful stuff for you, but this isn't one of them. Here's what you CAN do with string in ruby.  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html

Answer (score 7):

You can do this. I'd use `String#chars` which returns the ASCII numbers of each character in the string.

```
'abcdggg'.bytes
# => [97, 98, 99, 100, 103, 103, 103]
```

As you can see, the alphabet is sequential, each letter is one higher than the previous one. You can get it's position in the alphabet by taking 96 from the number.

Note that the upper-case letter is in a different position, but we can fix this using `String#downcase`.

To get all the alphabetical positions in a string (if it only has letters) we can write this method.

```
def alphabet_positions(string)
  string.downcase.bytes.map{|b| b - 96}
end
```

This will work unexpectedly if any characters aren't letters, tho.

Comment: This is what OP asked (ignoring every edge case)

Comment: My first name disagrees with this solution.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Granted, it's a limited solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can build a hash with position of a letter in an alphabet and then query this hash:

```
indexes = ('a'..'z').each_with_index.map{|l,i| [l, i+1]}.to_h
"stackoverflow".chars.map{|l| indexes[l]}
# => [19, 20, 1, 3, 11, 15, 22, 5, 18, 6, 12, 15, 23]
```

Comment: I like that this would handle the edge cases by returning a predictable `nil`.

Comment: Alternatively: `indexes = ('a'..'z').each.with_index(1).to_h` and `'stackoverflow'.each_char.map(&indexes)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do that :

```
def position(letter)
  letter.upcase.ord - 'A'.ord + 1
end
```

And then :

```
chars = ["s", "t", "a", "c", "k", "o", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "o", "w"]
chars.map do |char| position(char) end
 => [19, 20, 1, 3, 11, 15, 22, 5, 18, 6, 12, 15, 23]
```

See [ord](https://apidock.com/rails/String/ord) method for more information or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747126/find-a-letters-alphabetical-score)

Answer (score 1):

Below will give you the result you want.

```
str = "stackoverflow"

def conversion(str)
  arr = []
  str.upcase.gsub(/[A-Z]/){|m| arr << m.ord-64}
  return arr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `each_char` than `chars` because the latter creates an array that is immediately thrown out.

```
str.each_char.map{|al| al.ord - ?a.ord + 1}
# => [19, 20, 1, 3, 11, 15, 22, 5, 18, 6, 12, 15, 23]
```