# Need help assigning values to a new array then calculating those values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def solve(c)

  letter_values =('a'..'z').map.with_index(1) {|letter,value| [letter,value] }
  remove_vowels =c.gsub(/[aeiou]/, ' ').split()


end
solve("zodiacs")
```

The `letter_values` array has the alphabet letters with numbers. I need to assign those numbers to the `remove_vowels` variable, which should only return consonants to carry out a calculation later on. If `"z"` is return, I need to look in the array and take the value of `"z"` which is `26` and assign it as a value to `z` from the regex.

Comment: I don't understant what you want. `solve(zodiac)` should return `[25, 3, 2]` (values of `[z, d, c]`) ?

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear to me, could you provide some example inputs/outputs?

Comment: It's OK to say you're a newbie in the body of the question but you shouldn't pollute the title with that information. Please edit.

Comment: So once I have removed any vowels from the input string, i then need to match the consonants with the values stored in letter_values variable. So for example, after removing the vowels from zodiac, only z,d,cs are left, i then need to match those strings with the values held in the range. Thanks

Comment: input is zodiacs. output should be "z" = 26 and so on matching the consonants after removing the vowels. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def solve(c)
  letter_values =('a'..'z').map.with_index(1) { |letter,value| [letter,value] }.to_h
  remove_vowels = c.gsub(/[aeiou]/, '').split('')

  hash = Hash.new
  remove_vowels.map { | consonants | hash[consonants] = letter_values[consonants]}
  hash
end
```

solve("zodiacs") => this will return `{"z"=>26, "d"=>4, "c"=>3, "s"=>19}`

Or you could use `#each_with_object`, the result will be the same; it cleans the code up quite a bit:

```
def solve(c)
  letter_values =('a'..'z').map.with_index(1) { |letter,value| [letter,value] }.to_h
  remove_vowels = c.gsub(/[aeiou]/, '').split('')

  remove_vowels.each_with_object({}) { |constanant, hash| hash[constanant] = letter_values[constanant]}
end
```

solve("zodiacs") => this will return `{"z"=>26, "d"=>4, "c"=>3, "s"=>19}`

Answer (score 2):

So you want the index in the alphabet of each letter?

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325920/ruby-inbuilt-method-to-get-the-position-of-letter-in-the-alphabet-series)

`letter_values = ('a'..'z').map do |l| l.bytes.first - 96 end`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So once the vowels are removed from the string "zodiacs", i need to match the consonants with the values stored in the letter_values variable. I need for example z =26 and so on. Thanks